# using namespace std and then including boost?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

Consider the following C++11 program:

```
 #include <stdhdr1>
 #include <stdhdr2>
 #include <stdhdr3>

 using namespace std;

 #include <boost1>
 #include <boost2>
 #include <boost3>

 int main()
 {
 }
```

Where `stdhdrn`is a standard library header, and `boostn` is a boost header.

Is there ever a situation where this won't compile?

Furthermore given some additional user code in main, is there ever an ambiguity (or other error) caused by opening the std namespace that cannot be resolved by explicitly qualifying the ambiguous (or erroneous) entity?

(For example because of ADL considering the open std namespace or otherwise?)

(Put another way, can boost handle being included after an open std namespace?)

Comment: It does, obviously, beg the question: why not just put the `using namespace` after the boost includes?

Comment: Why not remove `using namespace std;` altogether and forget about it?

Comment: Simple answer, don't `using namespace` at all.

Comment: That doesn't inspire much confidence in those codebases.

Comment: Quite a number of large codebases open std in the global header to save on boilerplate code but there is a discussion on whether or not it is good or bad practice [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there would be a problem since `std` does not contain a namespace called `boost`, so there still won't be any name clashes.

As for ADL: ADL only considers the enclosing namespace of a class type. Any functions that would be found by ADL for a boost class type must be somewhere within the `boost` namespace.

You will be able to resolve all entities simply by doing `::std_entity` for standard library entities and `boost::boost_entity` for boost entities.

However, I can't think of a good way to prove this without explicitly trying it out. Of course, the sure way to avoid any problems is to not do `using namespace std;` and, if you really have to (which you don't), only do it after all inclusions.